# Can an iOS app have a custom design for the phone call pop-up alert?

Tags: ios, popup

The program has a button, and after button is tapped, it goes to the system dialler to make the call to the 'phone number.

Comment: Would it be possible to add some more details to your question? Do you want to create a local notification that allows a user to initiate a call (when your app is not in the foreground)? OR do you want to initiate a call when your app is active (in the foreground)?

Comment: http://oy39lc.axshare.com/#p=home

Comment: 1 screen its prefered, but if can't make call without alert, is it possible to change design of call alert? Make red and add icons

Comment: i want initiate a call

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about making a phone call using a `tel:` or `telprompt:` URL, then no. There is no way to customize the user experience.