# How can replace the default alert for calling phone?

Tags: ios, swift

How can replace the default alert for calling phone?

I use below code:

```
guard let number = URL(string: "tel://" + number) else { return }
UIApplication.shared.open(number)
```

After it calls a default alert which we can see on the screen below.

[image]

But I need to change it alert, for example, text for buttons, add title etc. 
But I don't know how it makes will be thankful for any help.

Comment: I don't think this is in your control...

Comment: You can't do that using `UIApplication.shared.open(number)` because it calls the OS to open the link, in our case "tel://". You can make your own alert before showing this dialogue. But in the end user will see that one in any case.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41153217/custom-design-for-ios-call-alert

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way to customize this native experience.